# Adding a 4th column to an array and making the new column = the concatenated values of the first 3 columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello in google app scripts sheets I am trying to figure out how to add a 4th column to an existing and fully populated 3 column array.  The 4th column is going to be set to a concatenated and manipulated string of the first 3 columns.

My end goal is to create a sql database insert string out of the first 3 values.  For example if the array row is 1,2,3 column for would be set to insert into table values (1, 2, 3);  (not a programmatic database connection just the actual SQL string for the insert)

Could you help me with the syntax or pseudo code of how I would work this into the array?  Your help is super appreciated

Something like:

```
const range=SheetHistory.getDataRange();
var array=range.getValues();

/*pseudo code*/
array = array + 4th column //add a 4th column to the array or move data to a new 4 column array
For x = 1 through end of array ++x) // loop through array
 Array [x,4] = [x,1] & [x,3] [x,4] // set column 4 for each row = to a concatenated string derived from columns 1,2,3 for that row
next x // repeat until end of array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the whole array and add value of fourth column at each row index as

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
array[i]["4th column"]=String(array[i]["1"])+String(array[i]["2"])+String(array[i]["3"]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Thanks @ysf Done

Comment: Nice I did realize you could just add into a column without manipulating the variable and I was fumbling the syntax.  This really helps to see your code thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function addAColumn() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()+1);//add a column here
  var vs=rg.getValues().map(function(r){return[r[0],r[1],r[2],String(r[0])+String(r[1])+String(r[2])];});//fill it here
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

This function will add one column to a 3 column spreadsheet and the fourth columns is filled with the String sum of the first 3 columns.

Comment: I was thinking about doing this but the trouble was I go through several iterations and there is a performance hit switching between active sheets each time so I was looking to keep the work load in the array to avoid the performance hit, but I did try this and it totally works.

Comment: I don't understand why you would be switching between active sheets.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple, the trick is that your array is a 2D array made up of rows (first dimension) and columns (second dimension). So doing a *For each row in the array, concatenate all the columns and store the result in a new column in the row* would do it.

### For example:

```js
function makeSQLString() {
  const range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var array=range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
    array[i][3]=String(array[i][0])+String(array[i][1])+String(array[i][2]);
  }
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize you could just add it in I thought maybe it was necessary to adjust the variable.  Thanks for your explanation and the syntax really helped me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Please [accept and/or upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it works for you.